# ElGamal digital signature. why mod p-1 in delta?

Tags: signature, modular-arithmetic, elgamal-signature

Im trying to figure out why $\delta$ in the signature part of ElGamal has mod $p-1$ when $\gamma$ has mod $p$?

$\gamma = \alpha^k \mod p$

$\delta = (x-a\gamma)k^{-1} \mod p-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically because of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem): if $a$ is not divisible by $p$ then $a^{p-1} = 1$ $mod$ $p$. A part of the expression for $\delta$ appears as a power of $a$ in the ElGamal signature verification equation, which "happens" to work because it is reduced modulo $p-1$ so Fermat's little theorem applies.

Comment: Why can you when proving the verification, raise gamma when it is mod $p$? 

$\alpha^x = \beta^\gamma \gamma \delta \mod p$

Comment: What's really going on is that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are both themselves powers of $\alpha$. You need to expand them to see what's going on.

Comment: Yea I $a^x=\beta^\gamma \gamma^\delta$ and get: $\alpha^{a\gamma}\alpha^{k(x-a\gamma)k^{-1}}$ which gives $\alpha^{a\gamma}\alpha^{x}\alpha^{-a\gamma}$, So since $\alpha^{a\gamma}$ and $\alpha^{-a\gamma}$ cancels each other we can do this?

Comment: That's it, basically. You need the $mod$ $p-1$ so that the power is "off" by a multiple a $p-1$ (which by F.l.t. means the power is one). Otherwise you couldn't cancel the $k$'s.